# Recovery mode, can't repair packages

Tags: boot, networking, recovery-mode

I just used `apt-get dist upgrade` && `reboot` and when it restarted the kubuntu logo flashed a few times and then my screen turned black. So I restarted with the spash disabled, and found that it couldn't detect my GPU or start the GUI (simple desktop display or something). So i loaded recovery mode and tried to repair packages.

It waited a while then told me it failed to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com

So i dropped into the shell and ran this

```
$ /etc/init.d/networking start
ok
$ ping 8.8.8.8
Connect: network is unreachable
```

What do i do?

Edit: connecting an ethernet cable instead of using wifi doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

As I'm not certain what caused the issue, I recommend you try booting into an older kernel. If you have grub, on boot, just select advanced options, and select a kernel version older than your, and see if the issue is resolved.

Comment: why do you think booting with older kernel will work?

Comment: There might have been a kernel update that broke the drivers.

Answer (score 0):

The older kernel had the same problem, and while i eventually got it to connect to the internet, the new package didn't fix it.  The solution was just to reinstall Kubuntu.